# Coding Newb:Python: Issues returning value from recursive function

Tags: python, function, recursion, return

This code is giving me a headache.

```
time = epoch_years ## this value is 50.13452189.....

def timex(t):  ## isolaing and return decimal value of t
    print("t;",t)
    if t < 1:
        return t  
    else:
        timex(t-1)

result = timex(time)
```

I can't seem to get the value t returned after isolating the fractional value.  There's probably an easier way to achieve what i want, though I'm hellbent on understanding why this code isn't working.   --Result-- keeps coming back as --None--

Comment: `return timex(t-1)`

Comment: ^^ Just add the `return` before `timex` function.

Comment: @rdas Write this in as an answer :)

Comment: rdas - that worked, though I'm not understanding why it worked.  The If statement when -true- should just return the value t to the function call.  -else- at that point shouldn't be invoked because t < 1.....

Comment: @denver-coder "should just return the value t to the function call" That function call is usually the recursive call in the last line. Without a ``return``, the value is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

As @rdas said in his comment:

Change:

```py
def timex(t):  ## isolaing and return decimal value of t
    print("t;",t)
    if t < 1:
        return t  
    else:
        timex(t-1)
```

to:

```py
def timex(t):  ## isolaing and return decimal value of t
    print("t;",t)
    if t < 1:
        return t  
    else:
        return timex(t-1)
```

The `return` before `timex(t-1)` is the only change. I believe it works because the `return` will terminate the loop.